# Openldap Insufficient access (50) on command ldapwhoami

Tags: openldap

I created a user tom as follow

```
dn: uid=tom,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
cn: Tom
sn: Novembre
uid: tom
```

Then add password for this user

Finally I'm trying to test the credencials using command ldapwhoami

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -D "uid=tom,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" -W
```

I get the error

```
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Insufficient access (50)
```

Does it come from my type of user?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Maybe the ACL, Openldap server start with hardcoded ACL default values

Comment: Added ACL  in slapd.conf, but having the same error : access to dn.base="" by * read
access to *
        by self write
        by users read
        by * auth
access to dn.sub="dc=example,dc=com" attrs=userPassword
    by users auth
access to dn.sub="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    by * read

Comment: Tried ACL (but bind fails again)  access to attrs=userpassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using a DN and password, I guess you want the **simple** authentication method, and you should pass the `-x` flag to `ldapwhoami`. Otherwise it assumes you want SASL, and you probably don't have any suitable SASL mechanism configured.